# Compressing a CFDataRef object?

Tags: macos, compression, core-foundation

Looking through the documentation for CFDataRef I can't see anything that will compress a CFDataRef after it has been created. For example, in my code I do something like this:

```
CFIndex byteSize = GetExportByteSize();
const UInt8 *exportData = GetExportDataPtr();
CFDataRef dataRef = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, exportData, byteSize);
CFDictionarySetValue(dict, kAS_ExportDataKey, dataRef);
```

Basically, I'm creating a CFDataRef from a chunk of memory that is about 2MB in size. Doesn't sound like much but in practice for this application it is too much data.

Is it possible to compress the CFDataRef object after creation? Or might it be better to compress the raw data it points to first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to compress the CFDataRef object after creation?

`zlib.h` is one option.

> Or might it be better to compress the raw data it points to first?

How much time do you want to spend developing this? How well can the data structure's size be reduced using what you know of the input data? Is the implementation in zlib (or another lib) unacceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the zlib suggestion. Due to time constraints I was hoping for a CFCreateCompressedDataRef() or similar function. In a future update I can reduce the amount of data that needs to be stored.

Comment: @StephenBlinkhorn you're welcome. using zlib is pretty simple, but it's not a one-liner. also note that there are better algorithms, and some are better suited for particular purposes. For images or audio, there are a few options in the frameworks (which may yield smaller sizes than zlib, but will likely be more complex to implement than zlib, if audio).

Comment: Well spotted, I am indeed working on an audio app but the data I'd like to compress isn't audio signal data as such. It is mostly session data - music sequences, control data, parameters etc. It should compress very well (compressing the files in the finder reduces the file size by 70%) but this will have to wait for an update.

Answer (score 1):

I should note that OS X now has SecTransform https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/System/Reference/SecTransform_header_reference/Reference/reference.html which you can use to do ZLib compression on CFData. I have an example of using it here https://github.com/Machx/Zangetsu/blob/master/Source/CWZLib.m

```
-(NSData *)cw_zLibCompress {
    SecTransformRef encoder;
    CFDataRef data = NULL;
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;

    CFDataRef inputData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, [self bytes], [self length]);
    if (inputData == NULL) { return nil; }

    encoder = SecEncodeTransformCreate(kSecZLibEncoding, &error);
    if(error) { CWZLIBCLEANUP(); return nil; }

    SecTransformSetAttribute(encoder, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, inputData, &error);
    if (error) { CWZLIBCLEANUP(); return nil; }

    data = SecTransformExecute(encoder, &error);
    if (error) { CWZLIBCLEANUP(); return nil; }

    NSData *compressedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:(__bridge NSData *)data];
    CFRelease(encoder);
    CFRelease(inputData);

    return compressedData; 
}
```